# loop to limit attempts at validation

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out a simple way to limit the amount of attempts on a field(s) through a while loop in javascript. Just doesn't seem to want to loop but the validation is still working. Here is the code I was trying to use:

```
 function validateForm() {
     x=document.forms["Form"]["name"].value;
     var i=0;
     var sum=0;
     do {
         sum += i;
         i++;
     }
     while (i < 3)

     if (x==null || x=="") {
         alert("First name must be filled out");
         return false;
     }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: Pray tell - Why would you want (or need) to limit the amount of attempts for validation. Besides the person could just either reload the page or disable Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to store the variable outside of the function:

```
 var numOfTries = 0;

 function validateForm() {

     if(++numOfTries > 3) {
         alert('You have reached the maximum number of tries!');
         location.replace("error_page.html"); // do something about it
     }

     x = document.forms["Form"]["name"].value;

     if (x == null || x == "") {
         alert("First name must be filled out");
         return false;
     }
```

Comment: Or keep it in a closure. Or as an object property.

Comment: Trying to keep it simple enough for OP to understand, especially for one who does not know how loops and functions work.